# MongoDB & MapReduce and insanely slow performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've stored about 700000 docs in my Mongo instance. It runs on 2GB VPS so ultimate speed is not to be expected. I use NodeJS & Mongoose to do the job.

Docs are in format like:

- 1st level key
- 1st level key

  - 2nd level key A

    - 3st level key A
  - 2nd level key B

    - 3rd level key 1

      - 4th level key A
      - 4th level key B
      - 4th level key C
      - ...
    - 3rd level key 2
    - 3rd level key 3
    - ...

avgObjSize is 3191 so they are not the biggest and not the smallest.. basically lists of short texts.

So what I need to do is to match certain values against all values found in 4th level key C in all 3rd level keys. The tricky part is that the document will be returned only if XX% of those match values are found in the 4th level key Cs.

I've tried MapReduce so that everything happens in the map function and it emits only preprocessed objects, I've tried returning all docs and postprocessing after, I've tried to use map function to output only 4th level key Cs and I've tried using Mongo's own functions like $all etc.

Problem is that everything is insanely SLOW. I mean like less than 500 documents per second. The collection is only going to grow so my question is that I'm a just missing something how to properly use Mongo or is it just that slow with tasks like these? I read previous questions and there was some issues with MR in Mongo being slow but this isn't slow, this is crawling.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your structure, I'd advise you to restructure your documents into more efficient format. Matching using 4th level keys is expected to be slow. Either move them up, or make them documents of their own.

Comment: Ok. Not sure why it would affect the speed because with mapreduce I'm not querying for that criteria, I'm just running 4th level thru a loop or is it somehow slower to run for loop for foo.bar.oz than foo.bar? However if the only solution is to restructure the data, Riak here we come.

Answer (score 0):

> avgObjSize is 3191

So 3.1MB * 700,000 is about 2.1GB roughly. That means that your working set might exceed your current RAM amount as you most likely know, judging by the content of your question.

Another point to take into consideration here is that you are loading 3.1MB into RAM which is a considerable amount for each document.

You should also consider that there is already a speed reduction due to the JS engine being JS and not the native C++ coding of MongoDB, and single threaded of course.

> Problem is that everything is insanely SLOW. I mean like less than 500 documents per second.

Indeed you are also looking for where a 4th level key of each 3rd level key might exist in each of itselfs key. That's a fair amount of looping and dodging about to get to your result.

Most likely you are suffering from recursion problems.

> Riak here we come

I doubt that will help, this query will be slow where ever you go. Instead you should look into how to design a schema based around your accession patterns, as you should when designing scalable technologies.

Comment: Actually for whatever reason Mongo isn't using all that much memory. Mongo's docs say it will use all available memory but not in our case. If looping is the problem, why fetching everything without processing is as slow as with processing? Doesn't make sense to me. But you are right, this isn't something I expect Mongo to handle "in real-time". Riak is our next step because frankly, Mongo sucks on so many levels and only reason it was chosen to begin with was the query capabilities. At least with Riak we can easily get more processing power with inexpensive OpenVZ VPSes.

Comment: @jimmy Hmm if memory is low then that could be another problem, I didn't know that part, maybe your readahead settings need modifying? http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/05/10/thursday-5-diagnosing-high-readahead/